# IIS7 theoretical limits

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, limitations

I am looking for information on some of the limits (hard-coded or theoretical) for IIS7 and NLB for website hosting.  I have looked around but haven't found anything concrete yet.

On a basic, single server IIS7 setup (Server 2008 x64), is there a limit on how many websites you can host on a single server?  Or a theoretical limit on concurrent web requests?  I'm not talking about memory limits or resource utilization, I simply mean is IIS7 either hard-coded or limited config-wise to only support a maximum number of websites?  1,000?  10,000?  More?

Also, does adding a second server via Microsoft's NLB into the mix reduce any of these theoretical limits?

I will be looking into capacity planning and resource limits later, but for right now I was just trying to find any documentation on what the theoretical limits are of IIS7 itself.

Thanks.

**Update:** Just saw [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2006/04/12/HOWTO-Maximize-the-Number-of-Concurrent-Connections-to-IIS6.aspx) with some info on IIS6.  If anyone knows if these limits and/or server tweaks still exist for 2008/IIS7, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [David Wang](http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2005/06/30/About_David_Wang.aspx) on the Microsoft IIS team, there are no limits to the number of websites supported by IIS ([see post here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=31137867&threadid=31137861)) other than hardware limitations.  Although that answer related to IIS6, I have to assume it is the same for IIS7.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Funny - I just found a blog post by David Wang as well, and just came back here to update my initial post :)

Comment: Actually there is a limit; the MaxValue of whatever data type they use to enumerate the websites.